# how to calculate 2 late mark as one half day absent

Tags: php, codeigniter

In attendance management system in codeigniter, I want to calculate 2 latemark as 1 half day and 3 late mark as 1 full day absent. How to do it?

```
$latemark_halfday= $this->Crud_model->GetData('attendence','late_time',"emp_id='".$_SESSION['SESSION_NAME']['id']."' and LEFT(date,7)='".date('Y-m')."'",'','','','');

$checklate= count($latemark_halfday)/2;
```

Comment: where is `GetData` defined ?

Comment: it is function in model GetData($table,$field='',$condition='',$group='',$order='',$limit='',$result='')

Comment: if `$latemark_halfday` gives you the number of times a student was absent in a day then why can't you create a switch or conditional statements to satisfy your algo? what exactly is the issue? what is your function currently doing that it shouldn't be doing?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the cleanest way to do it:

```php
/**
 * @param array $latemark_halfday
 *    An array of late marks.
 * @return array
 *    The first item is the calculated fullday absent.
 *    The second item is the calculated halfday absent.
 */
function calculate_absent($latemark_halfday) {
        $fullday_absent = (int) floor(count($latemark_halfday) / 3);
        $halfday_absent = (int) floor((count($latemark_halfday) % 3) / 2);
        return [$fullday_absent, $halfday_absent];
}
```

You may check this function with unit test:

```php
<?php

$tests = [
        ['input' => [1], 'expected' => [0, 0]],
        ['input' => [1, 1], 'expected' => [0, 1]],
        ['input' => [1, 1, 1], 'expected' => [1, 0]],
        ['input' => [1, 1, 1, 1], 'expected' => [1, 0]],
        ['input' => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'expected' => [1, 1]],
        ['input' => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'expected' => [2, 0]],
        ['input' => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'expected' => [2, 0]],
        ['input' => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'expected' => [2, 1]],
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
        $latemark_halfday = $test['input'];
        $count = count($latemark_halfday);
        list($expected_fullday, $expected_halfday) = $test['expected'];
        list($fullday_absent, $halfday_absent) = calculate_absent($latemark_halfday);

        // tests
        if ($expected_fullday !== $fullday_absent) throw new Exception("count: $count: fullday: expected $expected_fullday, got $fullday_absent"));
        if ($expected_halfday !== $halfday_absent) throw new Exception("count: $count: halfday: expected $expected_halfday, got $halfday_absent"));
        echo "latemarks: $count, fullday: $fullday_absent, halfday: $halfday_absent  [pass]\n";
}
```

Result:

```
latemarks: 1, fullday: 0, halfday: 0  [pass]
latemarks: 2, fullday: 0, halfday: 1  [pass]
latemarks: 3, fullday: 1, halfday: 0  [pass]
latemarks: 4, fullday: 1, halfday: 0  [pass]
latemarks: 5, fullday: 1, halfday: 1  [pass]
latemarks: 6, fullday: 2, halfday: 0  [pass]
latemarks: 7, fullday: 2, halfday: 0  [pass]
latemarks: 8, fullday: 2, halfday: 1  [pass]
```